# How ros_control can be customized to a dynamixel based omni directional mobile base

Tags: ros, navigation, 3d-slam, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I got to know that [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ros_control?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22ros_control%22) is very much helpful while making a mobile-robot(Specially for autonomous navigation). I am not find any good technical explanation and how it customized to our robot.

What all are the advantages of using ros_controller for a mobile base.Is it really required?. What all are the problems if it is not using. I want to use it for making navigation stack based slam.

It would be great if some one who already used this give some key points.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200393/how-ros_control-can-be-customized-to-a-dynamixel-based-omni-directional-mobile-base./) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the main advantages of using ros_control is that you can reuse existing robot-agnostic code, such as the Gazebo simulator backend and robot controllers. For onmidirectional bases, there is currently no officially supported controller (only diff-drive), although there are implementations [out there](https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory/steered_wheel_base_controller) that expose ROS APIs compatible with the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2015-01-07**:
We already seen that steered_wheel_base_controller.  Dynamixel has an ros driver.  ros_control http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_motor.  So I am thinking which will less head ache- using ros_dynamixel or building a ros cotrol using this [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ros_control?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22ros_control%22) framework.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-01-26**:
Using one does not mean not using the other. `dynamixel_motor` provides hardware access, while `steered_wheel_base_controller` implements the inverse kinematics map between twist and joint commands. The functionality of the packages is orthogonal, you could consider leveraging both.